# Akka source code study

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, intellij-idea, akka

After spending some time on Scala, I try to study on Akka project, find that '←' used instead of '<-' in Akka, my question is how to input '←' from keyboard, the symbol seems only can be used in Akka. Another question is that, if analyze the Akka source code, which IDE is the best suitable, I have tried Eclipse and IntelliJ, both are not good.

Comment: The akka team uses some non ASCII symbols, mostly for the different types of arrows. I believe if you set your IDE to use UTF 8 as the scala file encoding things should compile. Not sure how to enter the symbol from the keyboard though.  Maybe it's something in eclipse to translate => and <- into their utf 8 counterparts.

Comment: I use eclipse and Eclipse does convert arrows. As @cmbaxter suggests, set the File encoding to UTF-8, then you are set. Go to General →  Workspace → "Text file Encoding". I am not an IntelliJ user but I am very positive that it does support this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akka uses Scalariform in the build and that does the conversion between <- and ← automatically.